# How to programmatically specify page range to print in browser (using javascript or css)

Tags: javascript, css, printing, cross-browser

I want to print from the second to second-last page in browser, 
how can I specify the range before calling `window.print();` from javascript.

This is my style for media print

`<style type="text/css" media="print">
        .pageBreak
        {
            page-break-before: avoid;
            page-break-after: avoid;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
            height: 100%;
        }
        @page { 
            size: landscape;
        }
</style>`

Thanks

Comment: http://vikku.info/codesnippets/javascript/print-div-content-print-only-the-content-of-an-html-element-and-not-the-whole-document/ will this help you?

Comment: Place the content which you want within a `div` and load its content into the print window.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this would help you

**Java Script**

```
var content = document.getElementById(“mycontenttoprint"); 
var printer = document.getElementById(“printiframe").contentWindow; 
printer.document.open(); 
printer.document.write(content.innerHTML); 
printer.document.close(); 
printer.focus(); 
printer.print();
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="printiframe" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute"></iframe>
```

Please let me know if you face any troubles.

Comment: Thanks @Rajasuba, what I want to achieve is, to be able to pragmatically put range in print preview dialog, when `window.print();` is called. Could you help me with that